# Java NIO SocketChannelServer fails to send 2nd object to Socket Client

Tags: java, nio, java-io

I have implemented a NIO Based SocketChannerl Server that delegates JOBs to Socket clients.

The Server able to send the very 1st job java object to client successfully. When the second object is send, i see below exception on client side:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1381)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.cloudcoder.builder2.server.Builder2Server.safeReadObject(Builder2Server.java:370)
    at org.cloudcoder.builder2.server.Builder2Server.runOnce(Builder2Server.java:294)
    at org.cloudcoder.builder2.server.Builder2Server.run(Builder2Server.java:273)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Due to this the client disconnects and reconnects to the server. Even after reconnect, the very 1st object is successfully transferred to the client; second object send fails and this goes into the loop.

From various other SO questions, i understand that this exception could happen if we use new OOS on server side to send data every time to client. For writing the Java object i am using the [SocketChannerl.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) API.

**Object Send Code:**

```
// Generate the ByteBuffer from Submission object
Job job = getNextJobToProcess();
ByteBuffer jobByteBuffer = getBuffer(job);

if (jobByteBuffer != null) {
   LOGGER.info("Capacity of buffer is {}", jobByteBuffer.capacity());
   while(jobByteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
       int noOfSourceCodeBuffer = socketChannel.write(sourceCodeBuffer);
       LOGGER.info("{} no of bytes of job buffer written to the socket " 
          +  "channel {}", noOfSourceCodeBuffer, this);
   }
   success = true;
}
```

**Job Java Object to ByteBuffer converter:**

```
/**
 * Utility method generates byte buffer from a object which ISA {@link Serializable}
 *
 * @param obj instance of {@link Serializable}
 * @return ByteBuffer
 * @throws IOException
 */
private ByteBuffer getBuffer(final Serializable obj) throws IOException {
    // Create ByteArrayOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

    // write the Serializable object into ObjectOutputStream
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);

    // Create a ByteBuffer with the size of byteArrayOutputStream
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArrayOutputStream.size());

    // copy the ByteArrayOutputStream content to ByteBuffer
    buffer.put(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

    // mark it for read
    buffer.flip();

    return buffer;
}
```

As per the design the NIO server accepts the connection from legacy `java.net.Socket` client. Once the client is connected, The NIO server starts delegate the JOBs to the client; then client process the JOB and send the result back to the server. Once the server receives the result, it considers the client as free and ready to send the next JOB. This chain will continue until the client is explicitly shutdown.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, is JOB just the word "job" or is it an acronym for something? Also, can you show the code that puts the object into the ByteBuffer and the code that then sends the buffer to the socket?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, JOB is just word job. Edited to job. also added code snippets.